# To bring string data to one hot vector for machine learning

Tags: python-3.x, one-hot-encoding

everyone. I have a list with strings:

```
labels = ["Synonym", "Antonym", "Not relevant", "Synonym", "Antonym"]
```

There are  3 different labels and I want first to refer them to numbers 1,2 and 3 and then build one hot vector from them, like for example for label 3 --> 0
            0
            1
Have sombody an idea how to do it?

Answer (score 1):

A simple, library-less solution would be:

```
labels = ["Synonym", "Antonym", "Not relevant", "Synonym", "Antonym"]

mapping = {label: i for i, label in enumerate(set(labels))}

one_hot = []
for label in labels:
    entry = [0] * len(mapping)
    entry[mapping[label]] = 1
    one_hot.append(entry)
```

Result: `[[0, 1, 0], [0, 0, 1], [1, 0, 0], [0, 1, 0], [0, 0, 1]]`.

But you might want to look into sklearn, specifically [`sklearn.preprocessing.OneHotEncoder`](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.OneHotEncoder.html).

Comment: but my problem is now i get a list of numpy array instead of numpy matrix of the form (num_instances x
num_classes)